# $K$ and $L$ homeomorphic, then $C(K)$ is isomorphic to $C(L)$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, lattice-orders

Can someone sketch the proof (or give me some reference) of the following fact : If $K$ and $L$, compact and Hausdorff spaces, are homeomorphic then the lattices $C(K)$ and $C(L)$ are isomorphic.  (I am aware this is half of Kaplansky theorem, but I'm curious to know why)

Thank you.

Comment: Let $h \colon K \to L$ a homeomorphism. Consider $h^\ast \colon C(L) \to C(K); \; h^\ast(f) = f\circ h$. I'm not sure which lattice structure you're considering, but for the obvious one, it's a lattice isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\xi :K\longrightarrow L$ be a homeomorphism. Then $T_{\xi }: C(L)\longrightarrow C(K),$       $T_{\xi } (u) =u\circ \xi $ is an isomorphism.